# R group_by one variable or (not and) another

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, data.table

I have a dataset with two variables. As a simple example:

```
df <- rbind(c("A",1),c("B",2),c("C",2),c("C",3),c("D",4),c("D",5),c("E",1))
```

I would like to group them by the first component **or** the second, the desired output would be a third column with the following values:

```
c(1,2,2,2,3,3,1)
```

If I use `dplyr` and `group_by` and `cur_group_id()`, I would get groups by the first **and** second component, obtaining therefore

```
c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

Can anyone help me in an easy way, it could be either base R, dplyr or data.table, to obtain the desired group?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `igraph` could be a helpful tool for you

```
library(igraph)
df$grp <- membership(components(graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE)))[df$X1]
```

which gives

```
> df
  X1 X2 grp
1  A  1   1
2  B  2   2
3  C  2   2
4  C  3   2
5  D  4   3
6  D  5   3
7  E  1   1
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(X1 = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E"), X2 = c(1L,
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```